# About some basic functor in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

Why does this  `fmap (replicate 3) Just "JOHN"` return this  `[Just "JOHN",Just "JOHN",Just "JOHN"]` ? I know that   `fmap (replicate 3) Just "JOHN"` is equivalent with  `fmap (replicate 3) Just $ "JOHN"`, but why does that even compile ? How can we apply `fmap` to
`Just` which isn't even of concrete type ?

Comment: It takes `Just` as second parameter, so this is the `fmap` with as `Functor` a *function*. If you use `fmap (replicate 3) (Just "JOHN")`, you make use of the `Maybe` as `Functor`.

Comment: I didn't even know ```Maybe``` is a ```Functor```. What is ```fmap``` ? Why is the output in my code like that ?

Comment: `fmap = (.)` for the function functor (aka `(->) a`). So your code is `(.) (replicate 3) Just "JOHN"`, which simplifies to `(replicate 3 . Just) "John"`.

Comment: For the `(->) a` instance of `Functor`, `fmap` is defined as `fmap = (.)`, so you constructed a function `(replicate 3 . Just)`, and `(replicate 3 . Just) "JOHN"`, will create a list of `Maybe`s.

Comment: @Johnny: why do you think `Just` does not have a concrete type? Its type is `a -> Maybe a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functor `f` is a type constructor with an associated function `fmap` that "lifts" a function of type `a -> b` to be a function of type `f a -> f b`.

Both `Maybe` and `(->) r` (the partially applied function constructor) are functors.

```
-- When possible, apply the function to the wrapped value 
-- and wrap the result. Otherwise, return Nothing
instance Functor Maybe where
   fmap f Nothing = Nothing
   fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)

-- Compose the two functions
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap f g = f . g
```

Your expression uses the function instance on the two functions `replicate 3 :: a -> [a]` and `Just :: a -> Maybe a`:

```
fmap (replicate 3) Just "JOHN" == (replicate 3) . Just $ "JOHN"
                               == (replicate 3) (Just "JOHN")
                               == [Just "JOHN", Just "JOHN", Just "JOHN"]
```

What you likely intended was to map `replicate 3` over the *value* `Just "JOHN" :: Maybe String`, making use of the `Maybe` instance.

```
fmap (replicate 3) (Just "JOHN") == Just (replicate 3 "JOHN")
                                 == Just ["JOHN", "JOHN", "JOHN"]
```

Comment: It's pretty clear now, but can you explain me why ```Just``` is has  ((->r)) type?

Comment: I mean, everything that needs to take one more parameter to return something has an  ((->r)) type ?

Comment: @Johnny: `Just` has type `a -> Maybe a`, or in canonical form `(->) a (Maybe a)`. Note that a functor `f` has kind `Type -> Type`, since the type of `fmap` is `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. It thus applies the type parameter `a` or `b` to `f`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, so is it true that any function I have x1 -> x2 -> .. xn is (->)x1 (something...) in canonical form at it will pattern match in case of fmap application with composition operator ?

Comment: Right; canonically, `x1 -> x2 -> x3` is `((->) x1 ((->) x2 x3))`. `(->)` is a right-associative operator. It's the left-associativity of function *appilcation* that lets you write things like `f :: a -> b -> c` and `f x y` instead of having to parenthesize them as `f :: a -> (b -> c)` and `(f x) y`, respectively.